# Vista locks up after ~10h. of activity

Tags: windows, windows-vista, 64-bit, freeze

I am experiencing a problem: Windows Vista completely freezes/locks up lately... It happened today twice - the mouse and keyboard stopped responding and I had to re-boot.

I checked the Application Events Log and I see these two errors: 
Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.

and then

The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) failed to load: 
SASDIFSV
SASKUTIL

---

I checked Help online and it points to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756390%28WS.10%29.aspx and suggests Updating the drivers.

I'm not sure why would I have problem with drivers and if so, how can I find out which drivers to update?

Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you by chance recently install anti-virus software?  And if so did the problems begin shortly after?

Comment: Hi,

I installed AVG 9 (upgraded to latest version) about month or a bit more ago

Yesterday I switched to Microsoft Essentials (uninstalled AVG) - it found 3 Trojans - not sure why AVG didn't pick it up

Anyway, do you think it may be related?
One more thing - every time after I re-boot this way I have to re-enter my passwords to my common sites in IE

Comment: Yes, forgot another thing, which may be related

Sometimes when I'm typing an answer in one of the forums, in the middle of the phrase I hear a strange noise and I can not type anymore, I have to click, in order to continue typing

Comment: Do I get modded down if I answer "this is by design"?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean? I don't think locking up Windows is "by design"

Comment: I got an answer to uninstall SMS if I have it installed.
How can I do that?

Comment: @Matt: I'm tempted to mod your comment up +1 funny

Comment: IMHO, it's not that funny when I'm facing a real problem.

BTW, what does "mod up" expression mean - I don't hang on these forums - don't know the inner culture

Comment: Here is http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/314141
 How can I find if I have it installed and uninstall it?

Answer (score 0):

I used instructions from http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/45480/q-how-can-i-uninstall-the-microsoft-systems-management-server-sms-2003-advanced-client.html - the time will tell if it will help with the problem

Comment: I actually wanted to add this as a comment - but didn't see the comment option. Not sure how to change it into the comment status.

Comment: You can't comment with less than 50 rep. Besides, this is an answer. Why should it be a comment?

Comment: You should associate your accounts in your user parameters, to regain ownership over the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check **Problem Reports and Solutions**

```
Start -> Problem Reports and Solutions
```

[image]

See if Windows recognizes there is a problem, can tell you what is causing it, and maybe if there is a solution.